# Can we create a Singleton class by having non-private instanceName?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Generally, I have seen instance variables in a Singleton class being kept private. But is it possible to keep it non-private? 
What if we declare an instance like this:-

```
final static SingletonClass singletonInstance= new SingletonClass();
```

Will it cause any problem for the class being a valid Singleton class?

Comment: You're really asking two questions here: Can we create a singleton class by having a non-private instanceName AND what will happen if I try to create a second object of a singleton class? Correct?

Comment: No. Second question is; is my approach of using final instance correct? @blahfunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ensures that is a single instance of that class in the system at any given time. The pattern is not saying anything about public/private

Implementations can vary as long as you have one single instance available.

In your case if all constructors are private and the rest of the classes will get access to the singleton like this `SingletonClass.singletonInstance` the singleton pattern will be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, that's better answer :)

Answer (score 1):

We make instance variable private because we want full control on it (In your case you are making it final and static, so before any one can use, it has value and later it can't be changed).

But there are few points against it:

1) If variable is private and not static, Usual singleton design will not initialize variable until somewhere we want to use it (Lazy loading).

2) We should minimize scope of variable/function as much as we can. If you don't want anyone to change it directly then do not expose it (better design)

Only plus point I can see is you do not have to worry about thread safety (In usual singleton you have to take care about it if you have multi threaded application)

Comment: Yes, I myself missed that plus point! Making it final means I need not worry about thread safety part. Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

The only visible difference depends on how the JVM handles itself.
Doing so, it is possible that the class is allocated before it is accessed.. this may not be true now, or ever, but this creates a dependency on the language implementation, whereas the classic approach leaves initialization in the hands of the first caller.

EDIT1:

Technically, it will still be a valid Singleton class, provided that the JVM ensures thread safety in such an access scenario. I would generaly avoid this approach since you have no way of synchronizing the creation in case it is necessary, which will violate the instance being a singleton.

Comment: Yes or No? Is making a final instance a correct solution?

Comment: How do access modifiers bring thread safety into picture? We can always take care of that part by focussing on Constructor or the getInstance method of Singleton class. Isn't it?

Comment: Access modifiers have nothing to do with it.. I mean that instantiating the class in this manner causes the first access to any class member to initialize the field. If this is done by two simultaneous threads and the JVM does not handle this in the way it is expected, you could end up with two instances..@shanti

Comment: Ok I got your point. So basically, if I make the getInstance method synchronized somehow, then whether I keep the instance "private static" or "final static", it has no bearing on the class being not Singleton, right?

Comment: It will still have bearing, since then you allow access to a potentially uninitialized field. @shanti.

Comment: So when and how does using this way of using "final static", can stop the class from being a valid Singleton class?

Comment: It should be thread-safe because static initialization is synchronized. This is similar to the holder pattern.

Comment: Let's say that two threads attempt to access this field for the first time. The field is static, so it would make sense it will be initialized only once. In this case, one would be tempted to assume that the JVM will handle this properly, by blocking one thread, initializing on another and then having the blocked thread obtain the already available reference.This design approach means that you trust your entire application's correctness on the CURRENT implementation of the JVM, provided that it works like that in the first place. Software changes, JVM is no different. @shanti

Comment: @fgb Should is not something I would ever depend on in software. Even if it is so at the moment, and has no apparent reason to change, is it really a risk you would be willing to take?

Comment: Ok, I meant it is thread-safe. It's in the specs so it's not implementation dependant: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Comment: Again, specs change.. I did not doubt that the JVM is properly implemented.. I am merely saying, I would not want to depend on that if I had the choice not to. @fgb

Comment: How can two threads try to access it simultaneously if I make the getInstance method synchronized? Let's say I do it. Doesn't it give a solution? I mean it is a flawed design, but a valid Singleton class nonetheless, right?

Comment: @shanti synchronizing will do the trick, so long as the synchronized block is the only place which invokes a constructor of the class.

Comment: Yes, that's how I had in mind. Too bad I didn't give the full class code. Basically, I wanted a getInstance method to invoke the class's private constructor.

Comment: You need to initialize an object instance within a static constructor, then synchronize the getInstance method by using it in a synchronized block.